# installing Ubuntu 21.10 on legacy BIOS only system

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, mbr

I have non-UEFI machine, with single SSD drive, without other OS on it and want to install Ubuntu 21.10 on it, via ISO image written on USB stick and via ubiquity, but without success.
On first boot from USB installation media I choose 'Ubuntu' and then 'erase disk and install', and installation passes well, but after rebooting it responds that there is no boot drive.
Please help.

Comment: (1) There's no "Ubuntu 21". Hopefully you meant Ubuntu 21.10 (Ubuntu 21.04 is out of support). (2) There isn't enough information for any meaningful answer. Does the installer/live media boots and you're able to install normally (i.e. without error messages) and then can't boot the installed OS? Or is it something else? Have you checked the ISO? Please [edit] the question according to all the comments.

Comment: The title still says 21, but you've not said if you're asking about Ubuntu 21.10 Desktop (ie. an ISO using the `ubiquity` installer) or Ubuntu 21.10 Server (ie. an ISO using `subiquity` installer) or something else.  On what device was the boot loader written to during your install?   It's provided to your before the install starts.

Comment: Please open BIOS settings and confirm the drive where you installed Ubuntu has the first priority in the boot order. Also telling us which machine you're trying to install is a good idea.

Comment: Make sure in Bios, AHCI is set instead of Raid.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair